# Where am I going wrong with evaluating this integral?

Tags: probability, integration

I can’t upload the picture, but I integrated and then had to evaluate
$$\int_{200}^{\infty}[(-xe^{-x/1000})-(1000e^{-x/1000})]dx$$
I apologize if the notation is a little wonky, asking from my phone because laptop is old. My problem is when I evaluate for infinity, I always end up with negative infinity divided by infinity which is undefined. Would this just default to 0 in the evaluation? I’m confused because the answer is essentially just evaluating for 200. I know usually when you evaluate for infinity you use a limit and it usually converges to either 0 or 1, but I don’t know what to make of this. What am I missing?

Comment: My bad worded it all poorly. The original integral was x * (e^(-x/1000)/1000. What I wrote above was the antiderivative. Apologize for the lack of clarity

Comment: $x*e^{-ax}=0 $ for any a>0

Comment: You need to do some l'Hopital.

Comment: Wow, duh. Feel a bit silly now lol, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**Via integration by parts and  L’Hospital Rule**

\begin{aligned}
\int_{200}^{\infty}\left(-x e^{-x / 1000}-1000 e^{-x / 1000}\right) d x 
= & 1000 \int_{200}^{\infty}(x+1000) d\left(e^{-x / 1000}\right) \\
= & 1000\left[(x+1000) e^{-x / 1000}\right]_{200}^{\infty}  -1000 \int_{200}^{\infty} e^{-x / 1000} d x \\
= & -1000\left(1200 e^{-\frac{200}{1000}}\right)+1000^2\left[e^{-x / 100}\right]_{200}^\infty \cdots (*)\\
= & -1200000 e^{-\frac{1}{5}}+1000000\left(-e^{-\frac{1}{5}}\right) \\
= & -220000 e^{-\frac{1}{5}}
\end{aligned}

(*)By L’Hospital Rule:
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x+1000}{e^{\frac{x}{1000}}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{100} e^{\frac{x}{1000}}}=0 .
$$